# How to make Rails app perform an action depending on if a checkbox is checked? (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a checkbox in a view called post_form.html.erb that someone uses to post. Here's the full code of it below:

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @post %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, :cols => 5, :rows => 5 %>
  </div>
  <div class="ItemContainer">
    <div class="ItemInput">Add your photo:<br>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div><div class="ItemCheckbox">
<label for="a">Run script?</label>
  <div class="ItemCheckboxAlign"><input type="checkbox" id="a"></div>
</div></div><br>
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The above is used to post and I use show.html.erb for the view. 
As you can see in the above code, there's a checkbox during the posting process. I want it so that if the checkbox is checked, certain action happens in my show.html.erb view (running a script in this case). If it's not checked, then I don't want to run the script.

Is the best method to store the boolean information on whether the checkbox was checked in the database? My question is, what's the RoR code to make the checkbox associate with the table value?

Comment: can that be done for making a <script> run if the checkbox is checked? I have updated the original post with more detail

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use jQuery for that:

```
$('#a').click(function() {
  $('#text').toggle();
});
```

Comment: instead of text, can I put in a <script> tag making a script run if the checkbox is checked, and not if unchecked? Let me update my original post

Comment: You would just remove the `$('#text').toggle();` line in my function above, and replace it with whatever script you want to run.

Comment: I tried this and it seems that the script runs regardless. Does it make more sense to create a new column in the "Post" table and attach a binary data to it? (i.e. whether checked is true or false)? I'd like to use your jQuery but it doesn't seem to be working as the checkmark is supposed to be associated with a post that is submitted

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#check_box_id').is(":checked")
```

to check if the checkbox is checked or not.